# Game Maker Studio HTML5 Text displaying problem

Tags: game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

In Game Maker Studio 2 text object is poorly displayed when i exporting my game to HTML5

[image]

DRAW event:

```
draw_set_font(fnt0);
draw_set_alpha(1);
draw_set_color(c_white);
draw_set_halign(fa_left);
draw_set_valign(fa_top);
draw_text_ext(x+24,y+16,msg,16,boxWidth);
```

Text in msg is defined in the STEP event and depends on the state (gameState) of the game.

```
switch gameState
{
case gameState.titleScreen:
scrTitleScreen();
break;

case gameState.charGen:
scrCharGen();
break;
}
```

gameState is defined in ENUM.

Tested in Opera browser 56.0.3051.99.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Are room's properties `Clear Display Buffer` and `Clear Viewport Backgroud` enabled?

Comment: Yes, Clear Display Buffer and Clear Viewport Backgroud are enabled. I noticed that this bug is manifested when the variable msg=@"sample text string". when i delete @ symbol everything is displaying ok. pic of this - https://ibb.co/QCXBqq8

Comment: Then just file a bug report (Help → Report a Bug).

Comment: yeah! sad that far from the only bug ...noticed that on the runtime v2.2.1.287 there is a problem with the layers (instance_create_layer) but on HTML5 only instance_create_depth works fine. "Draw text justify" asset on marketplace works fine! Thanks!